# Helm export YAML files locally (just use templating engine, do not send to Kubernetes)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want to export *already templated* Helm Charts as YAML files. I can not use Tiller on my Kubernetes Cluster at the moment, but still want to make use of Helm Charts. Basically, I want Helm to export the YAML that gets send to the Kubernetes API with values that have been templated by Helm. After that, I will upload the YAML files to my Kubernetes cluster.

I tried to run `.\helm.exe install --debug --dry-run incubator\kafka` but I get the error `Error: Unauthorized`.

Note that I run Helm on Windows (version helm-v2.9.1-windows-amd64).

Answer (score 77, accepted):

We need logs to check the `Unauthorized` issue.

But you can easily generate templates locally:

```
helm template mychart
```

> Render chart templates locally and display the output.
>
> This does not require Tiller. However, any values that would normally
> be looked up or retrieved in-cluster will be faked locally.
> Additionally, none of the server-side testing of chart validity (e.g.
> whether an API is supported) is done.

More info: https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_template/

Comment: `Error: stat incubator/kafka: no such file or directory`

Comment: Requires helm 3

Answer (score 29):

Amrit Bera's solution will only work with local helm chart, per the details of your question you want it to work with remote helm chart, that's a feature that will be added to Helm v3 (Work in Progress currently).

RehanSaeed posted the following workaround (https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/4527)

Basically:

```
mkdir yamls
helm fetch --untar --untardir . 'stable/redis' #makes a directory called redis 
helm template --output-dir './yamls' './redis' #redis dir (local helm chart), export to yamls dir
```

The good thing about this is you can mix this technique with weaveworks flux for git ops + this gives you another option for using Helm v2 without tiller, in addition to the Tiller Plugin (which lets you run tiller locally, but doesn't work smoothly).

Comment: +1. This worked for me and I think this should be the accepted answer since it also features a full working example.

Answer (score 12):

Straight from the `helm install --help`

```
To check the generated manifests of a release without installing the chart,
the '--debug' and '--dry-run' flags can be combined. This will still require a
round-trip to the Tiller server.
```

Comment: Is there a way to still do this * after* installing? I'm getting an error that a release already exists.

Comment: `helm uninstall` then rerun the command should work

Answer (score 4):

If you want to see only the resolved YAML you can use

```bash
helm template .
```

I prefer to see it on a file

```bash
helm template . > solved.yaml
```

Answer (score 3):

> This is not the answer for the question but this post on stackoverflow
> is the first one which was displayed in searchengines when i was
> searching for a solution of my problem and solved it by myself reading
> the Helm CLI docs. I post it here anyway because maybe someone else is
> searching for the same usecase as i did.

For already installed Helm charts on a Kubernetes cluster you can use the following command to export/download all information for a named release:

```
 helm get all <release-name>
```

or

```
helm get all <release-name> > installed-kubernetes-resources.yaml
```

If you only want e.g. the `manifests` or `values` instead of all, just replace the `all` command appropriately (get more details by using `helm get --help`):

```
Usage:
  helm get [command]

Available Commands:
  all         download all information for a named release
  hooks       download all hooks for a named release
  manifest    download the manifest for a named release
  notes       download the notes for a named release
  values      download the values file for a named release
```

If you want to export the information for a named release with a distinct revision you can use the flag `--revision int` in your get command (`helm get all --help`). To list all possible revisions of your named release just use the command `helm history <release-name>`.

My Helm CLI version:
`version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.5.0", GitCommit:"32c22239423b3b4ba6706d450bd044baffdcf9e6", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.15.6"}`